# JavaScript: Group and sum items in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Take the below array of objects `myData`:
It's current output is:

```
console.log(myData);

Object { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "015" }
Object { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "012" }
Object { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "022" }
Object { mins: 28, name: "N/A", label: "0330",   count: "63", id: "033" }
Object { mins: 17, name: "3pp", label: "Free",   count: "49", id: "080" }
Object { mins: 10, name: "5pp", label: "SC006",  count: "23", id: "087" }
```

The **desired output** should be grouped by `label` and summed `mins` and `count` values, like below:

```
Object { mins: 30, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "30", id: "022" }
Object { mins: 28, name: "N/A", label: "0330",   count: "63", id: "033" }
Object { mins: 17, name: "3pp", label: "Free",   count: "49", id: "080" }
Object { mins: 10, name: "5pp", label: "SC006",  count: "23", id: "087" }
```

**Q:** How can I achieve the above desired output?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: id should be unique for every item

Comment: @alex Is that the *only* requirement?

Comment: you can use https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

Comment: What should happen with `name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the array methods

- reduceRight (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)
- filter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- reverse (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

and a little bit of type conversion.

```
// reduceRight so that the latest id is in the output (instead of the first)
var output = input.reduceRight(function (a, b) {
    // locate existing key (if any)
    var k = a.filter(function (e) { return (e.label === b.label) })[0];
    if (k !== undefined) {
        // update object
        k.name = "N/A";
        k.mins += b.mins;
        k.count += +b.count;
    }
    else {
        // coerce to nubmer
        b.count = +b.count;
        // insert new object
        a.push(b)
    }

    return a;
}, []).reverse();
// we need the reverse because we do a reduceRight
```

---

Note that the output count is a number (not a string), if you want a number you can easily do that by removing the `b.count = +b.count;` and updating the `k.count += +b.count;` to `k.count = String(+k.count + +b.count);`

---

**Stack Snippet**

```js
var input = [
    { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "015" },
    { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "012" },
    { mins: 10, name: "N/A", label: "UK GEO", count: "10", id: "022" },
    { mins: 28, name: "N/A", label: "0330", count: "63", id: "033" },
    { mins: 17, name: "3pp", label: "Free", count: "49", id: "080" },
    { mins: 10, name: "5pp", label: "SC006", count: "23", id: "087" },
]

var output = input.reduceRight(function (a, b) {
    var k = a.filter(function (e) { return (e.label === b.label) })[0];
    if (k !== undefined) {
        k.name = "N/A";
        k.mins += b.mins;
        k.count += +b.count;
    }
    else {
        b.count = +b.count;
        a.push(b)
    }

    return a;
}, []).reverse();


so.log(output)
```

```css
body {
   font-family: verdana;
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<script>
  var so = {
    log: function(e) {
       document.getElementById("a").innerText = JSON.stringify(e, null, '     ');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This will fail if same `label` separated by other elements.

Comment: @bentinata - I'm pretty sure not. The filter takes care of getting the right element (it doesn't take the last element). Could you give an example input that fails? (I tried swapping a couple of elements around without any problem). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Or just basic loop. You should've understand the essential of looping.

```
var newArr = [];

for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for (newArrIterator = 0; newArrIterator < i; newArrIterator++) {
    if (newArr[newArrIterator] && newArr[newArrIterator].label === myData[i].label) {
      newArr[newArrIterator].count = (parseInt(newArr[newArrIterator].count) + parseInt(myData[i].count)).toString()
      newArr[newArrIterator].mins = parseInt(newArr[newArrIterator].mins) + parseInt(myData[i].mins)
      newArr[newArrIterator].name = "N/A"
      found = true
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    newArr.push(myData[i]);
  }
}
```